# Can I add additional lighting to a standard motion security light?

Tags: security

I have a 2-story house with walkout basement, so my existing under-eave security light is essentially 3 stories above grade in the back. I swapped out the existing 100w flood bulbs in my motion security light with 24w (250w eq) LED flood bulbs which helped but due to the size of the yard I'd like to add a few high-lumen LED panels. Can I wire standard 3-wire light fixtures like these panels to turn on/off with the integrated motion sensor?

Answer (score 1):

The wattage limit of most fixtures is such due to heat concerns. It's difficult to say how much current the sensor circuitry will handle. You're safe up to the limit on the sticker, though.

Otherwise, swap out your fixture for a standalone sensor and abide by its stated limitations.

Comment: The original bulbs were 100w x2 = 200w. I currently have 24w x 2 = 48w so have plenty of room for additional lighting. That's the beauty of originally-incandescent fixtures.

Comment: The original bulbs don't tell you anything unless they shipped with the fixture. That's like filling your tires to the pressure on the tire. Read the sticker (on the fixture *and* the car).

Comment: I take that back. Obviously the circuitry is tolerating 200w. I meant as a maximum in case you want to go higher.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't always work, because newer LED light-sensor combos  may use 12-24V internally (this makes the sensor much less expensive, and the LEDs prefer it).

However given your unit with its Edison screw-in  bulbs, it is surely 120V.  Should be fine.